# Repeating a loop when it reaches the end

Tags: ruby

I am trying to conceptualize the iteration of two loops

```
numbers_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
add_to_array = [1,2,3,4]
```

While the `numbers_array` iterates, `add_to_array` iterates simultaneously adding both elements together at the same time. The caveat is once `add_to_array` reaches the end, it starts over adding its element to the next index in `numbers_array`. So at `numbers_array[4]` we would be adding `add_to_array[0]` then adding `numbers_array[5]` to `add_to_array[1]` and so on. This process would repeat until we reach the end of the `numbers_array`.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit to show the desired result (array) for your example.

Comment: My comment above and comments on my answer make it abundantly clear that we don't understand your question. You have read those comments but for some reason have not clarified your question. That earns a downvote from me (which I'll retract if you clarify your question).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for [`Enumerable#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) and [`Enumerable#cycle`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle):

```
numbers_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
add_to_array = [1,2,3,4]
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 4]
numbers_array.zip(add_to_array.cycle)
#⇒  [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 1],
#    [6, 2], [7, 3], [8, 4], [9, 1], [10, 2]]
```

Now do whatever you want with the array returned. E.g. to reduce the zipped result summing elements, map ro [`Enumerable#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum):

```
numbers_array.zip(add_to_array.cycle).map(&:sum)
#⇒ [2, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 10, 12, 10, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

It works by using the `%` operator to cycle through the indexes.

```
numbers_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
add_to_array = [1,2,3,4]

numbers_array.map.with_index do |n, i|
  n + add_to_array[i % add_to_array.length]
end
```

A cool method that's similar, if you didn't want to start over at the next array, would be `.zip`

https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip

Answer (score 0):

```
add_to_array.zip(*numbers_array.each_slice(add_to_array.size)).
             map { |a| a.sum { |e| e.to_i } }
  #=> [16, 20, 13, 16]
```

`e.to_i` is needed to convert `nil` values to zeros. See [NilClass#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/NilClass.html#method-i-to_i).

Comment: I doubt this is what OP expects. Please check my answer for the desired output (last line.) It’s still my wild guess, though.

Comment: @mudasobwa, I had noticed. I asked the OP to clarify by showing the desired result.

Comment: _“at `numbers_array[4]` we would be adding `add_to_array[0]` then adding `numbers_array[5]` to `add_to_array[1]`”_...

Comment: @mudasobwa, is that not what I'm doing (except I'm not mutating `add_to_array`)?

Comment: “at `numbers_array[4]`” wording already implies there are at least five elements and your result contains only four.

Comment: I interpreted "at `numbers_array[4]` we would be adding `add_to_array[0]`" as being followed by, "with the sum saved in `add_to_array[0]`". Either interpretation is possible. We'll just have to wait for a clarification. In any event, we've provided the OP with a bonus, by answering two questions.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
numbers_array.map { |e| e + add_to_array.rotate!.last }

# => [2, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 10, 12, 10, 12]
```

Drawback: add_to_array is mutated by `rotate!`